# dataLayer with multiple rows is Possible?

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-datalayer

Hi I need send multiple orders from a backoffice process. But Only send the last.

My code look like this

Best Regards And Thx in advance

```
<head>
...
<script type="text/javascript">
    dataLayer = [];

dataLayer.push({"orderID":"6488jmk","precio":"2.00","plataforma":"PAYMENTPLATFORM","moneda":"EUR","campana":"CLIENT","usuario":"TESTING-382","tipo_pago":"Pago TESTING","proveedor":"CLIENT","tracking":"","affiliateid":""});
dataLayer.push({"orderID":"7209all","precio":"2.00","plataforma":"PAYMENTPLATFORM","moneda":"EUR","campana":"CLIENT","usuario":"TESTING-385","tipo_pago":"Pago TESTING","proveedor":"CLIENT","tracking":"","affiliateid":""});
dataLayer.push({"orderID":"6723drw","precio":"2.00","plataforma":"PAYMENTPLATFORM","moneda":"EUR","campana":"CLIENT","usuario":"TESTING-379","tipo_pago":"Pago TESTING","proveedor":"CLIENT","tracking":"","affiliateid":""});
dataLayer.push({"orderID":"6488jmk","precio":"2.00","plataforma":"PAYMENTPLATFORM","moneda":"EUR","campana":"CLIENT","usuario":"TESTING-382","tipo_pago":"Pago TESTING","proveedor":"CLIENT","tracking":"","affiliateid":""});
dataLayer.push({"orderID":"6723drw","precio":"2.00","plataforma":"PAYMENTPLATFORM","moneda":"EUR","campana":"CLIENT","usuario":"TESTING-379","tipo_pago":"Pago TESTING","proveedor":"CLIENT","tracking":"","affiliateid":""});
</script>
<script>(function (w, d, s, l, i) {
        w[l] = w[l] || [];
        w[l].push({'gtm.start':
                    new Date().getTime(), event: 'gtm.js'});
        var f = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
                j = d.createElement(s), dl = l != 'dataLayer' ? '&l=' + l : '';
        j.async = true;
        j.src =
                'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=' + i + dl;
        f.parentNode.insertBefore(j, f);
    })(window, document, 'script', 'dataLayer', 'GTM-XXXXX99');</script>
</head>
```

Comment: Hi 
Can you share about how is the OrderID will be used? 
If you want to send transaction data, maybe you can add an "event" parameter.

Comment: Currently everything is configured in google tag manager and every time a transaction is completed, it correctly captures it with the dataLayer.push. But this time we want from the backoffice to be able to send various requests for subscription renewals that come directly from the payment gateway to our own php script and therefore without javascript support. That is why we decided to try to do a manually run php that will report all raw renewals. Rudimentary but to test and we come across this incident. That only the last one rules. Excuse my pitiful english

Comment: If I understand it correctly, you want to send those transaction hits from your backend like "PHP". In this case you can skip the GTM and Datalayer. You can send the hit directly with "Google Analytics Measurement Protocol"
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters
Use php to send request directly when you get the callback from your gateway.

Comment: If you want to go JavaScript way as before. I guess your transaction hit is sent from PageView with order information. In this way It would only send the last element in array.
In my experience, one GA hit only contain one transaction data. You can add the parameter something like "event : customize_purchase".
Add a trigger type "custom event" with the event name "customize_purchase". It would send multiple transaction hit based on your array's length(or you can say order's amount).

Answer (score 0):

It is "possible" in the sense that is does not cause errors. However, with identical keys each new row will overwrite the previous one, and you will only to be able the data that is pushed immediately before the first "event" key (in your example the native gtm.js/"container loaded" event). This is almost certainly not what you want.

You would need to push a nested array to the dataLayer:

```
items = [
{"orderID":"6488jmk","precio":"2.00","plataforma":"PAYMENTPLATFORM","moneda":"EUR","campana":"CLIENT","usuario":"TESTING-382","tipo_pago":"Pago TESTING","proveedor":"CLIENT","tracking":"","affiliateid":""},
{"orderID":"7209all","precio":"2.00","plataforma":"PAYMENTPLATFORM","moneda":"EUR","campana":"CLIENT","usuario":"TESTING-385","tipo_pago":"Pago TESTING","proveedor":"CLIENT","tracking":"","affiliateid":""},
{"orderID":"6723drw","precio":"2.00","plataforma":"PAYMENTPLATFORM","moneda":"EUR","campana":"CLIENT","usuario":"TESTING-379","tipo_pago":"Pago TESTING","proveedor":"CLIENT","tracking":"","affiliateid":""},
{"orderID":"6488jmk","precio":"2.00","plataforma":"PAYMENTPLATFORM","moneda":"EUR","campana":"CLIENT","usuario":"TESTING-382","tipo_pago":"Pago TESTING","proveedor":"CLIENT","tracking":"","affiliateid":""},
{"orderID":"6723drw","precio":"2.00","plataforma":"PAYMENTPLATFORM","moneda":"EUR","campana":"CLIENT","usuario":"TESTING-379","tipo_pago":"Pago TESTING","proveedor":"CLIENT","tracking":"","affiliateid":""}
];
dataLayer.push(items);
```

Within GTM, you'd need to iterate over the array in a custom HTML tag or something built via a custom template.